# minikube and ingress-dns issues with fedora and virtualbox?

Tags: kubernetes, systemd-resolved, minikube

I followed that setup instructions (I'm new to K8s)
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/addons/ingress-dns/

I enabled ingress-dns and that Ok.
I added `dns=dnsmasq` in NetworkManager.conf
I  added `server=/test/$(minikube ip)` in /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/minikube.conf

```
 nslookup  hello-john.test $(minikube ip)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Server:     192.168.59.100
Address:    192.168.59.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   hello-john.test
Address: 192.168.59.100
```

that works.
But if i try without specifying the minikube IP it does not anymore.

```
nslookup  hello-john.test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find hello-john.test: NXDOMAIN
```

so I edited the systemd/resolved.conf  and added the minikube IP.
Then here it works fine, ... except for the extrnal domains, which are failing then using a fallback.

What Am I missing here?